# Uniqueness of finite measures

Tags: measure-theory

By uniqueness of finite measures I am referring to the elementary result that if two finite measures on the same measurable space agree on a $\pi$-system that generates the underlying $\sigma$-algebra, they also agree on the entire $\sigma$-algebra.

My question is about the proof of this as given in the book of Williams, ''Probability with Martingales''. The proof is given in the appendix (A1.4.). The equalities marked by $(*)$ start with
$$\mu_1(B\setminus A) = \mu_1(B) - \mu_1(A)$$
I don't get how this could be true. I can just take disjoint $A$ and $B$ with $\mu_1(B) < \mu_1(A)$. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of context the statement doesn't make sense, but in context the author is proving the $\mathcal  D$ is a Dynkin system, in particular that if $A,B\in\mathcal D$ and $A\subset B$ then $B\setminus A\in\mathcal D$. The assumption $A\subset B$ unstated.

Comment: Of course. The stability under differencing requirement is only for sets included in other sets in the collection.

Answer (score 2):

Stan's answer is exactly right, and you should accept his. Just for completeness, I've included excerpts of the relevant sections for people who may not have access to the book.

On the previous page, where he defines "$d$-systems":

> [image]

The author is arguing why something is a $d$-system, so they are implicitly referring to parts (a), (b), and (c), and therefore in arguing for part (b), the fact that $A\subseteq B$ is assumed.

> [image]